# Trying to permanently change my "default storage engine" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, storage-engines

I'm using MySQL Workbench and I just simply would like to know how to change permantly forever my default storage engine to InnoDB, because the default one, MyISAM doesn't let me have foreing keys in my tables.  Does anyone know how to avoid doing this constantly? After the laptop turns off or the service stops/resets?

Please, help!

I've tried running in the Query 1 the line:

```
SET default_storage_engine = InnodDB;
```

but it doesn't work.

Also with my default time zone using -3:00 but it affects only for a time, after turning my laptop at the next day it goes back to some weird thing.
BTW I've also tried configurating in the Options File in the Workbench but idk if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: And how would we know if you're doing it wrong, when we can't see what you're doing?

Comment: Did you **read the documentation**, e.g. [16.1 Setting the Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engine-setting.html)? *"The default engine is `InnoDB` in **MySQL 8.0**. You can specify the default engine by using the `--default-storage-engine` **server startup option**, or by setting the `default-storage-engine` option in the **`my.cnf` configuration file**."*